# Passing Data Between 2 Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

Im building a an app that contain `TabNavigator`.
How in the first screen I initalize data that I also need in the second screen.
I want to know what is the best way to pass params between those screens

I've tried to use `Navigation.setParams()` from the first screen but in the second I didn't get it.

```
const PaymentsStack = createStackNavigator({
        Payments: {
            screen: PaymentsScreen
        }
    }
);

const GraphsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Graphs: GraphsScreen
});

createBottomTabNavigator({
    PaymentsStack,
    GraphsStack
});
```

```
class PaymentsScreen extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const importantData = await GetDataFromServer();
    };
}
```

```
class GraphsScreen extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const importantData = ??;
    };
}
```

I want to know how to get the `importantData` that returned to `PaymentsScreen` in `GraphsScreen`

Thank You

Comment: Why don’t you use state management tools like redux, MobX  to manage the entire app’s state?

Comment: This is an option but currently I want to solve this without any state manager

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that through `getParam` and `setParam`

```
class PaymentsScreen extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const importantData = await GetDataFromServer();
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ importantData });
    };
}


class GraphsScreen extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const importantData = this.props.navigation.getParam('importantData');
    };
}
```

`getParam` & `getParam` could solve the issue in the case you have in your question ... but I guess this use case is commonly managed by one of the popular global state management tools like [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux) or [unstated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unstated) as @Edison mentioned in his comment...

Comment: I can't get the param that I set in the second screen.

Comment: @aviyamivgi is the value `undefined` ? and in shich event handler you tried to grab it ? cause if you're component is aleardy mounted, you 'll need to get the value inside your `componentWillRecieveProps` event

Comment: I don get it ?? ... I meant to call these handlers inside your screen that you render by your **TabNavigator** like `PaymentsScreen `

Comment: The value is `undefined` in `componentWillRecieveProps`

Comment: @aviyamivgi would you share you code for both screens ... the setter and the getter ?